# tensorflow probability installation

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to install "TensorFlow-Probability" for windows offline without going through internet so that I can avoid network firewall issue, but I could not find any instruction about how to. Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have a physical copy of it? Otherwise you will need to use the internet, as it's hosted on GitHub

Comment: I was trying to see if anaconda cloud has it. But it only has a linux version. I saw a couple of zip files, but wasn't sure if they are windows. Do you know where I can download tar or zip files for windows? Also, once I download those files, can I use conda offline command to install the package offline?

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow-Probability is pure python, there is no need for a windows build of it.

You should be able to download the file from: https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-probability/#files

and pip install it in a conda or python environment.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you.  I downloaded the whl file and was able to installe using pip. It required tensorflow 1.3.1.

Comment: pypi does host several different versions of tensorflow-probability, go to https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-probability/, select `Release history`, select the release you need, select `Download files`